# Solve $y' + ky = 2x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $y' + ky = 2x$ with initial conditions
$y(0)=1$
$y'(0)=1$
**such that there exists a solution**.

Attempt: the problem is that I get a system of equations with 4 unknowns.

Comment: Why do you have $y'(0)$ specified for a first-order problem?

Comment: Perhaps, do you want to solve: $y'' + ky = 2x$?. Is $k$ a fixed constant? Has it to be determined?

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the homogenous equation is
$$y_h=A e^{-kx}$$
and a particular solution has the form
$$y_p=ax+b$$
so we find
$$y_p'+ky=2x\iff a+k(ax+b)=kax+a+kb=2x\iff a=\frac 2 k\land b=-\frac 2{k^2}$$
so the solution
$$y=y_h+y_p$$
Notice that with the initial conditions we have $k=-1$ and $A$ is determined with $y(0)=1$.

Comment: Sami, same comment as lab.  How do you know the OP didn't mistype and want $y''$ and not $y'$?

Comment: Why do you want that it to be  $y''$ and not $y'$? I used the initial condition $y'(0)$ to determinate the parameter $k$.

Comment: It's not that I want it to be anything; it's just that the OP gave a number of conditions that are overdetermined and it is unclear from his problem statement what he wants solved.

Comment: I don't think that's overdetermined, please look at my answer I used the two conditions and the question as it is makes sense to me.

Comment: You have assumed that $k$ is unknown; this is unstated.  Typically $k$ is a given and not an unknown.  More likely, the OP wants to solve the equation with $y''$ and not $y'$.  I could be wrong, but that is what is more typical.  In any case, the OP has said nothing about this and as such, his problem statement is incomplete.

Comment: Yes I agree with you and now I think that the four unknowns which  the OP talked about it are the two coefficients of $A\cos\sqrt k x+B\sin\sqrt k x$ and the two coefficients of the particular solution.